# Using composed xpath to locate an element and click on it

Tags: node.js, selenium, xpath, webdriver-io

I am trying to retrieve a list of elements using XPATH and from this list I want to retrieve a child element based on classname and click it.

```
var rowList = XPATH1 + className;
var titleList = className + innerHTMLofChildElement;

 for(var i = 0; i < titleList.length; i++) {
                if(titleList[i][0] === title) {
                    browser.click(titleList[i][0]);  //I don't know what to do inside the click function
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar implementation perhaps to what you are trying to do, however my implementation is perhaps more complex due to using CSS selectors rather than XPath. I'm certain this is not optimized, and can most likely be improved upon.

This uses the methods `elementIdText()` and `elementIdClick()` from WebdriverIO to work with the "Text Values" of the Web JSON Elements and then click the intended Element after matching what you're looking for.

http://webdriver.io/api/protocol/elementIdText.html
http://webdriver.io/api/protocol/elementIdClick.html

Step 1 - Find all your potential elements you want to work with:

```
// Elements Query to return Elements matching Selector (titles) as JSON Web Elements. 
// Also `browser.elements('<selector>')`
titles = browser.$$('<XPath or CSS selector>')
```

Step 2 - Cycle through the Elements stripping out the InnerHTML or Text Values and pushing it into a separate Array:

```
// Create an Array of Titles
var titlesTextArray = [];
titles.forEach(function(elem) {
    // Push all found element's Text values (titles) to the titlesTextArray 
    titlesTextArray.push(browser.elementIdText(elem.value.ELEMENT))
  })
```

Step 3 - Cycle through the Array of Title Texts Values to find what you're looking for. Use elementIdClick() function to click your desired value:

```
//Loop through the titleTexts array looking for matching text to the desired title.
for (var i = 0; i < titleTextsArray.length; i++) {
  if (titleTextsArray[i].value === title) {
    // Found a match - Click the corresponding element that  
    // it belongs to that was found above in the Titles
    browser.elementIdClick(titles[i].value.ELEMENT)
  }
}
```

I wrapped all of this into a function in which i provided the intended Text (in your case a particular `title`) I wanted to search for. Hope this helps!

Comment: What if I have a list of objects with the same title and I want to click specific element using it's number in array?

Comment: It's hard to tell without any knowledge of your html / element structure, but perhaps you need to find a more "unique" selector. If "title text" is all you have to go off of, webdriverio will most likely by default select the "First" element it comes across matching the desired selector. Can you provide an example of your element structure? in CSS Selectors you can do an "nth-child(#)" selector which would allow you to pluck an element based on it's position in a list, but it's a brittle way or selecting.

Comment: Yes, it does work! So I don't have to create the list, get element, etc.. I just specify child number as a parameter of the function that clicks element. Thank you very much!

Comment: No problem! - Happy to Help!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know node.js, but in Java you should achieve your goal by:

```
titleList[i].findElementBy(By.className("classToFind"))
```

assuming titleList[i] is an element on list you want to get child elements from